# JavaScript: Check if an array element is a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, numbers

I have an array of arbitrary elements and need to get only number elements.
I tried `arr.filter((c) => !isNaN(parseInt(arr[c])));` but that didn't work. I still have a full array. What is wrong here and what else can I do?

Comment: `c` *is* the value `arr[c]` is not defined.

Comment: What do you mean by “number elements”? That `parseInt` check is going to include strings that only start with digits. If the array elements are JavaScript numbers, you just need `typeof`; if you want to check for strings of a particular format, I’d recommend a regular expression.

Answer (score 7):

The first argument in the callback to `.filter` is the *array item being iterated over* - if `c` is the array item, then referencing `arr[c]` usually doesn't make much sense. Try using a simple `typeof` check instead:

```js
const arr = [3, 'foo', { bar: 'baz' }, false, 4, 5];
console.log(arr.filter(item => typeof item === 'number'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access an index using the numbers, change to this:

```
let newArray = arr.filter((c) => !isNaN(parseInt(c)));
                                                 ^
```

Further, you need to use the array which is returned by the function `filter`.